# c++ unordered map emplace Invalid arguments

Tags: c++, unordered-map, emplace

if I have this map

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int*> sockets;  //a map holding all active sockets
```

how come I can do this :

```
sockets[_myId]=(int*)lp;  //all ok - insert succeeds
```

but I can't do this :

```
if(!sockets.emplace(_myId,(int*)lp).second) { /*insert failed, act accordingly*/ }
```

Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
? emplace(#10000(...) && ...)
'
I don't understand why this happens. Thx for any assistance.

Comment: Try to sockets.emplace(std::make_pair (_myId,(int*)lp))

Comment: @vadikrobot emplace in this case will take 2 arguments - key and value. you're thinking of insert.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works for me. `std::unordered_map<std::string, int*> sockets;

bool foo(const char *p, int n)
{
 return sockets.emplace(p, &n).second;
}`

Comment: works for me too https://godbolt.org/g/C5jZUm

Comment: ..horrible idea though, c-style casts to a c-style pointer (array?) can't you use a vector of socket handles?

Comment: [works](https://ideone.com/JK5N0j), anyway c-style cast of pointer... brrr

Comment: Try to add compiler, platform, compiler option informations to your question

Comment: thank you all for your answers. @Richard ... I am still learning every day. What's a better way to write it then? The compiler is gcc (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.1.0 the only added option is -std=c++11

Comment: thank you all for your answers. @Biagio ... I am still learning every day. What's a better way to write it then? The compiler is gcc (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.1.0 the only added option is -std=c++11

Comment: no problem with: GNU C++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) version 4.9.2 (i686-w64-mingw32)

Answer (score 1):

> What's a better way to write it then?

This is an unordered map mapping some identifier with a number of sockets.

In BSD sockets, a socket descriptor is an int (or at least convertible to one) so lets stay with that.

It seems that there are more than one socket associated with each identifier. This argues for a vector.

so:

```
using socket_vector = std::vector<int>;
```

and

```
using ident_to_sockets = std::unordered_map<std::string, socket_vector>;
```

now we can append sockets to each ident:

```
sockets[ident].push_back(sock);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int*> something;
std::string a;
int* b;

something[a] = b;

// with emplace:
something.emplace(std::make_pair(a, b));

// also
something.emplace(std::unordered_map<std::string, int*>::value_type(a, b));
```